# How to prevent many clicks on a button that launches several sometimes a dialog by default? (android bug)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

Events of default click (eg a list):

```
listviewAvailables.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,final int position, long id) {
    showDialogStartStimulation();
}
```

});

**If I double-click fast, it starts 2 times the dialog ...**

**I have fixed this by using a variable:**

```
    boolean oneClickDialog = false;
        ...
        listviewAvailables.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,final int position, long id) {
            if(!oneClickDialog){
                showDialogStartStimulation();
                oneClickDialog = true;
            }
        }
    });
...
public void showDialogStartStimulation(){
..
pDialog.isShowing(){
oneClickDialog = false;
..
}
```

**Is not there a default solution?** Need more simple as a "return false" or something?
To correct this double click, **really should I apply my solution to all events of the app to launch a dialog?**

Comment: maybe you can try with if(!dialog.isShowing()){..}

Comment: do as @barn.gumbl said